# Why are lists giving different value?

Tags: python, arrays, list

**Hey Guys i am stuck with this problem **

```
alist=[[1],[2]]

la=alist[1][4%len(alist[1])] #when i run this i get the output 2

al=4%len(alist[1])  #when i run this i get the output 0
```

**Can someone explain why ?**

Comment: What we're you expecting? and why?

Comment: @khelwood i dont understand why calling la gives 2 , i do understand why al gives 0 . Can you explain what happening in la ?

Comment: @LEONARDO are you familiar with the modulo operation?
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-python-modulo-operator-what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-python-solved/#:~:text=The%20%25%20symbol%20in%20Python%20is,remainder%20of%20a%20division%20problem.&text=In%20the%20previous%20example%20a,and%20the%20remainder%20is%20returned.

Comment: `la` is an element of `alist[1]`. `alist[1]` is `[2]`. How could `la` be any value other than 2?

Comment: @DavidS Yes but i dont know what alist[1] is doing to the [4%len(alist[1])]

Comment: Since you know that ``4%len(alist[1])`` is zero, would you understand why ``alist[1][0]`` gives two?

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see values in variables. You could also split code to smaller parts - in `x = alist[1]`, `y = len(x)`, `z = 4%y` and use `print(x, y, z)` to see how it works. it is called `"print debuging"`. OR learn how to use real debuger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the index values of the list.

```
alist=[[1],[2]]
```

Here `alist[1]` is `[2]`, so `alist[1][0]` is `2`.

`4%1` is `0`.